# Array of Sprite with Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing a game for android using Andengine but I have a problem when I try to create each `Sprite`.

In my declaration I have

```
private Sprite[] bolaSprite = new Sprite[16];
```

and then I get a `NullPointerException` error trying to initialize the first `Sprite` :

```
bolaSprite[0] = new Sprite(249, 242, resourcesManager.bola_region, vbom);
```

The full error is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.kevingsoft.scene.GameScene.createSprites(GameScene.java:83)
    at com.kevingsoft.scene.GameScene.createScene(GameScene.java:58)
    at com.kevingsoft.base.BaseScene.<init>(BaseScene.java:36)
    at com.kevingsoft.scene.GameScene.<init>(GameScene.java:37)
    at com.kevingsoft.manager.SceneManager$1.onTimePassed(SceneManager.java:112)
    at org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler.onUpdate(TimerHandler.java:94)
    at org.andengine.engine.handler.UpdateHandlerList.onUpdate(UpdateHandlerList.java:47)
    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateUpdateHandlers(Engine.java:618)
    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:605)
    at org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine.onUpdate(LimitedFPSEngine.java:57)
    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:568)
    at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:858)
```

Can somebody tell me why that's happening ?

Comment: It just says "Error"? That indeed would be a flaw of IDE, framework, language or JVM.

Comment: yeah, it would help if you posted the error as well

Comment: *[...] then I get the error [...]* - Which error ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, debugging I found that it is a NullPointerException.

Comment: Please post the full error message, as the name of the error doesn't give us the source of the problem. That's the purpose of the stack trace.

Comment: At this line  at com.kevingsoft.scene.GameScene.createSprites(GameScene.java:83) which code exist?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that resourcesManager.bola_region and vbom are actually initialised before the createSprites method [not null]
also would it'd help if you would share your whole createSprites method